# jQuery UI Autocomplete value after mouse click is old value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget.
I need to use the selected text for further processing, direct after change or select.

But when a user clicks the suggested value, the typed value gets passed.

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: function( req, resp ) {
    $.post( "/echo/json/", {
        json: '["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"]',
        delay: 1
    }, function(data) {
        resp( data );
    }, "JSON" );
},
select: function (event, ui) { alert($(this).val())}
});
```

An example at this fiddle: (try typing "tes" and select a suggestion by mouse)

http://jsfiddle.net/M3Yur/

i need to use the input value. a change events uses the input value, it needs to work in both cases when a autocomplete item is selected, but also when just a value is typed so the alert is just for the example.

Any way to get around this?

EDIT:
i ended up using: `$(this).val(ui.item.value).val();` 
this solutions always gets the intended value after a change event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
select: function (event, ui) { alert($(this).val())}
```

To this:

```
select: function (event, ui) {alert(ui.item.value);}
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3Yur/4/

Comment: Thanx Jon/Jen, The alert is a example, i need to use the input value. a change events uses the input value, it needs to work in both cases when a autocomplete item is selected, but also when just a value is typed

Comment: You have both values. Maybe if we knew when the change event fires??

Comment: The suggestion did point me in the direction that works for me: $(this).val(ui.item.value).val(); works for me

Answer (score 2):

The `ui` argument contains the information you're looking for:

```
select: function (event, ui) { alert(ui.item.value); }
```